# Tagging or Labelling System For Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

Whats the closest to or best options for 'tagging' or 'labeling' files in Google Drive. Similar to how 'labels' work in Gmail ideally.

I guess will be via an add-on.

Ideal features include

- renaming tags
- advanced searching with tags

I understand Google Drive used to have tags but removed them.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use folders. As occurs with Gmail tags, a file in Google Drive could "have" several folders (to save a file to multiple folders use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd>).

- Folders could be renamed
- It's possible to search for files in a folder.

By the way, if you are using a G Suite account, another alternative is to use Workspaces.

For further details please read [Organize your files in Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375091?hl=en)